# C#: Memory allocation for Anonymous Variables

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I'm having a doubt regarding the memmory allocation for anonymous type variable.

if i declare a variable `int Vaiable_Name` it will allocate `4 bytes`

but in case of `Anonymous types` , what will happen , and when the memory will get deallocated ?

Need we deallocate that manually??

for example

`List<String> MyList=new List<String>{"0","1","0"}.Where(X=>X!="1").ToList();`

Here how much `bytes` will be allocated for `X`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't actually shown any anonymous types. You've shown a lambda expression. In this case, the compiler will effectively have created an extra method for you, like this:

```
private static bool SomeUnspeakableName(string X)
{
    return X != "1";
}
```

Then your code will be translated into this, effectively:

```
List<String> MyList=new List<String>{"0","1","0"}
       .Where(new Func<string, bool>(SomeUnspeakableName))
       .ToList();
```

... except *actually*, the compiler will create a single delegate instance in this case, and cache it. (And of course it will translate the uses of extension methods into normal calls to `Enumerable.Where` and `Enumerable.ToList`.)

So `X` ends up as a string parameter, effectively. At execution time, there's no such thing as a lambda expression (leaving expression trees aside). There's just a delegate created using the generated method.

Now if you *were* using anonymous types, like this:

```
var anon = new { Name = "Jon", Age = 34 };
```

then that would just create a new class, containing a `string` variable and an `int` variable, and with the same memory footprint as a normal class containing a `string` (which is a reference, of course) and an `int`.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet : i'm asking about the `X` in that LAMBDA expression

Comment: @Pramodh: And I've shown what happens to it. It effectively becomes a parameter in the generated method.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet :Thank you ...  If i use `for` loop and `if` condition instead of the above lambda exprassion , which will use more memory lanbda or `for - if` loop ?

Comment: @Pramodh: Given the complexity of what actually happens under the hood, it's very hard to say *exactly* what will occur after JITting. But the difference will be inconsequential. You're worrying about the wrong thing here - make the code as readable as possible.

Comment: Haha when I saw the question I immediately thought this is a Jon Skeet question

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> MyList = new List<String>{"0","1","0"}.Where(X=>X!="1").ToList();
```

This is not anonymous type. It is a collection initializer which creates a list containing 3 elements and then filters the initially created list.

Anonymous types would behave and consume the same memory as their non-anonymous type equivalent.

```
var foo = new 
{
    Prop1 = "value1",
    Prop2 = "value2"
};
```

would be the same as if we had a type:

```
class Foo 
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

...
var foo = new Foo 
{
    Prop1 = "value1",
    Prop2 = "value2"
};
```

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov : What about  `X`?

Comment: @Pramodh x is not a variable, its a delegate.

Comment: @RPM1984: No, X is the parameter in the lambda expression, which ends up being a parameter in a generated method.

Comment: Youre right, i was referring to the first part of the lambda (X =>). i was under the impression that lamba is saying "X" is a delegate, to which X!= "1" is handling.

Comment: @RPM1984: No, it's saying that X is a parameter within the delegate. The whole lambda expression is turned into the delegate. See my answer for the transformation that the compiler performs.